# ONLY application.html.erb html is showing

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make my first rails project and I'm running into this problem I haven't seen anywhere online.  Only html that I put inside application.html.erb file is showing.  The terminal says it started a GET for "/", and it will print to the terminal when I put a ruby 'print' in the index.html.erb, but that page still shows up blank.  I've tried deleting everything that I have added to the application.html.erb file, but that didn't help.  When I use the actual routes the pages are blank.  All of theses pages worked at one point, but I have changed something and for the life of me can't figure out what.  Any ideas as to what could cause something like this to happen?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is preferred if you can post elaboration with the question after a good research. Thanks!

Comment: Does your `application.html.erb` layout file have a `<%= yield %>` statement somewhere inside the `body` tag?

Comment: I had just figured that out when I saw your comment! Thanks, that was it! So simple, but I must have erased it on accident along the way.